# django sites default

Tags: django, django-sites

Many 'reusable apps' require django-sites.
There is annoying field "publish on" in admin interface, which I can't exclude because it has no default parameter (so the entry will be published nowhere. I tried). The model is described in the 'reusable app' so I don't want to change it.

How can I get rid of this annoying field?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Catching the [`pre_save` signal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/#module-django.dispatch) will allow you to inject a default value.

Comment: oh! http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods maybe even this will work. thanks!